# Возврат указателя из метода

Tags: c++, классы, указатели, методы

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class B {
public:
    void invoke(){
        cout << "invoke";
    }
};

class A{
public:
    B* test(){
        B b;
        auto *bb = &b;
        return bb;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    B *b = a.test();
    b->invoke();
    b->invoke();

    return 0;
}
```

Несколько вопросов по этому коду:

1. будет ли он корректен?
2. почему компилятор не ругается на return bb;
3. почему этот код работает, ведь  auto *bb локальная переменная(stack) и должна умереть со всеми вместе когда работа метода закончится (return)

Comment: А этом-то и есть главная беда c++, c++ все позволяют, как будто так оно и должно быть, а потом раз - и ub :). Зато думать заставляют)

Answer (score 5):

1. Что такое "корректен"? Не содержит диагностируемых ошибок компиляции? Да, с этой точки зрения код "корректен".

   Однако он порождает *неопределенное поведение* из-за того, что оператор `->` выполняет разадресование (indirection) возвращенного `a.test()` указателя с невалидным значением (invalid pointer value).
2. А почему он должен ругаться? Никаких нарушений, которые компилятор обязан диагностировать (согласно требованиям спецификации языка), в этом `return bb;` нет.

   Стоит однако помнить, что неопределенное поведение *может* выражаться и в отказе компилятора компилировать код программы.
3. Этот код не "работает". Он порождает неопределенное поведение.

Answer (score 4):

Нет, не будет. Хотя работать будет :)

1. Возврат указателя на локальную переменную некорректен.
2. Наверное, уровень warning'ов недостаточный... Visual C++ 2017 при /W4 ругается - "возвращение адреса локальной или временной переменной".
3. В вызове `invoke()` никак не используется указатель на объект, поэтому ему по барабану, что туда передается, указатель на что... Скорее всего, он будет нормально работать - хотя и не обязан (UB).

Примерно так.

Варианты исправления:

```
B* test()
{
    static B b;
    return &b;
}

B* test()
{
    return new B;
}
```

Первый вариант плох тем, что всегда возвращает один и тот же указатель; второй - тем, что потом нужно не забыть удалить созданный объект. Лучше воспользоваться интеллектуальным указателем типа `unique_ptr`, который его потом сам уничтожит.

Comment: Возврат указателя на локальную переменную некорректен. Это код не "работает". Он порождает неопределенное поведение. Решается это исползованеим new, в методe main делать delete b ?

Comment: @TomX01 Что вы понимаете под "не работает"? Формально - да, я написал, что это некорректно. Фактически - покажите мне хоть один компилятор, который не выведет "invoke". Спускайтесь иногда с горних высот идеальных (т.е. несуществующих) компиляторов на грешную землю :) Давайте иногда говорить как оно будет на практике, а не как должно быть. Если б все было, как написано - мы б еще в 1981 жили при коммунизме :)

Comment: Я понял что такой подхоd не верен. Как будет правильно вернуть указатель из функции? Сделать new и затем в main вызвать delete b ?

Comment: @TomX01 См. дополненный ответ.

Comment: @Harry `Фактически - покажите мне хоть один компилятор, который не выведет "invoke"` — это пока стековый кадр `invoke()` не налезает на `bb`. То есть любое изменение окружающего кода должно сопровождаться анализом в дизассемблере использования стека. А оно надо?

Comment: @Arhad Функция не виртуальная, разыменование `this` не требуется... Думаю, что компилятор просто воткнет `call` для конкретного адреса и не будет озадачиваться, какой там именно объект ее использует. Оптимизатор VC++ просто воткнул два вывода `invoke`... Без оптимизатора - воткнул в `rcx` адрес `this` и сделал вызов. Сам вызов - простой вывод `invoke`, без попыток разыменования... Кстати, работает даже при присвоении `b=nullptr` :)